# How to detect push notification if app is in background in ios app?

Tags: ios, mobile, push-notification

1.Push notification delegate methods are calling when app is in background in swift 3

2 if app is in foreground push notification delegate methods are calling.

3.Is it possible if app is in background to detect push notifications?

Comment: You have already written that in `1`.

Comment: you need to use the didReceiveRemoteNotification for silent push notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notification are managed by the system if your app is killed or in background.
The only kind of push that can wake up your app is a "**silent push notification**".
This explained inside [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html), if you need to trigger some long task in background after receiving one of them, just remember to create a background task. Check also this [link](https://medium.com/posts-from-emmerge/ios-push-notification-background-fetch-demystified-7090358bb66e).